# SQLite scalar function return type always string?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

If I select a date-typed column in sqlite without any functions, it returns me a proper .NET `DateTime` object:

```
// Returns .NET DateTime object
select date_column from test_table;
```

But the moment I use a scalar function, it always returns me a `string`:

```
// Returns string
select datetime(date_column) from test_table; 
select date(date_column) from test_table;
```

The reason I need this is for date rounding

```
// Rounds to month
select datetime(strftime('%Y-%M-01T00:00:00', date_column)) from test_table;

// Rounds to year
select datetime(strftime('%Y-01-01T00:00:00', date_column)) from test_table;
```

I tried implementing my own SQLiteFunction, but it still returns a string:

```
[SQLiteFunction(Name="round_date")]
public class RoundDate : SQLiteFunction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Expects 2 arguments:
    /// 1: date 
    /// 2: rounding (Month, Quarter, Year)
    /// </summary>
    public override object Invoke(object[] args)
    {
        DateTime date = SQLiteConvert.ToDateTime(args[0].ToString());
        DateTime result = date;
        switch (args[1].ToString())
        {
            case "Month":
                result = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
                break;
            case "Quarter":
                int quarter = (date.Month-1)/3;
                var quarterStart = quarter*3 + 1;
                result = new DateTime(date.Year, quarterStart, 1);
                break;
            case "Year":
                result = new DateTime(date.Year, 1, 1);
                break;
        }

        // function returns a DateTime object.
        // But executing the statement returns a string
        return result;
    }
}

// Uses custom function, but still getting String
select round_date(date_column, 'Year') from test_table;
```

I know I can typecast/convert the string result manually.

But is there any way to force the select statement to return a DateTime object automatically?

**[Edit 1]**

I understand that Dates and DateTimes are not one of the natively-supported data types in sqlite.

I also know that I can manually convert the formatted strings to DateTime objects.

However, `select date_column from test_table` actually returns .NET DateTime objects. I assume the System.Data.SQLite implementation does this conversion automatically.

```
var selectStmt = sqlite.CreateCommand();
selectStmt.CommandText = "select date_column from test_table";
// ==============================
// ==============================
// Returns System.DateTime object
var this_is_a_DateTime_object = selectStmt.ExecuteScalar();
// ==============================
```

So I was expecting this same behaviour when using date(), datetime(), and my own SQLiteFunction implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated before, you can build a table with DATETIME type for a column, which returns a DateTime datatype in .NET.

Once you use any of the internal functions or Custom SQLiteFunctions it reverts it to an internal (non-date) data type.

There is a funny hack that can be used if you really want to avoid the String data type, this appears to be the ONLY way I can force it to return a DateTime data type in .NET after some level of date manipulation (so far). ***And I'm not really keen on it myself***...

If you define a table like such...

```
CREATE Table test2(id bigint, name nvarchar(500), DT datetime)
```

The query result of the third column is a DateTime.

So following the below logic (again this is ugly, but maybe will inspire someone with more ideas) will return a date time that has been modified by the internal datetime function...

```
CREATE TABLE output (id bigint, name nvarchar, dt datetime)
;
INSERT INTO output
SELECT id, name, DateTime(dt,'+5 years') FROM Test2
;
SELECT * FROM output
;
DROP TABLE output
```

Executing this as a single statement will fill one datatable with the result as expected DateTime Datatype in column 3, shifted by 5 years.
In your code if you can use a unique output table name for each call then the approach is safe from conflict with multiple statements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and workaround. The workaround is far from perfect, but it answers my original question, so I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a way to force the System.Data.Sqlite to automatically return the .NET DateTime datatype for you in this instance. Here's what's happening. Let's say your table definition looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_column DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

As you already noted, there's really no such thing as a data type in SQLite. But, as you also noted, the library is clearly handing you a native DateTime value back in this instance. My guess is the same as yours: it's using the semi-arbitrary wording of DATETIME as your request to undertake this helpful conversion on your behalf.

To test this, I added a clearly invalid date into one of my DATETIME columns and the library threw the exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Now, to answer your question of why you don't get this same benefit using one of the date/time functions, the answer lies in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> Notice that all other date and time functions can be expressed in terms of strftime():
>
> date(...) strftime('%Y-%m-%d', ...)
>   time(...) strftime('%H:%M:%S', ...)
>   datetime(...) strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ...)
>   julianday(...) strftime('%J', ...)
>
> The only reasons for providing functions other than strftime() is for convenience and for efficiency.

So you're not *really* calling date/time functions. You're calling a formatting function whose return time is--you guessed it--a string. I made a few failed attempts myself at trying to cast the result of a function back to a datetime, like so:

```
select (date(...) as DATETIME), ...
```

But unfortunately, you can only typecast to one of SQLite's native storage classes using the type affinity name (one of: NONE, TEXT, REAL, INTEGER, or NUMERIC).

So it looks like you're back to having to take care of the conversion yourself after the fact. (As will I.)

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite databases there are no storage data type for "Date and time"

You can convert the datatype after a SELECT command to standard .Net DateTime format.

```
Query : "SELECT ID, DateModified FROM Customer"
string id = reader.GetInt64(0).ToString();
DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)reader[1];
```

SOURCE: http://techreadme.blogspot.de/2012/11/sqlite-read-write-datetime-values-using.html

I'm sorry the above information applies to SQLite versions 1 & 2. SQLite3 does include datatypes although they are implemented differently than Standard SQL Databases.

https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SQLite but, from what I've read, there is no native data type for dates and times.  If your original query is producing a result set that the SQLite ADO.NET provider interprets as .NET `DateTime` values then I can only assume that it is based on format.  In that case, you might be able to use `strftime` to output in that same format and get the data as `DateTime` values automatically.  It appears that that format may be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" in .NET terms.

Comment: Tried this, but doesn't work. Formatting the output to match DateTime.ToString("g") format still returns string.